# can't add HttpServlet class in j2ee project

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, servlets

in eclipse java ee, when I right click on my project, new , class, I only as a superclass : java.lang.Object when I'd like to use javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.

I'm on kubuntu , new to java ee and can't find a solution online, thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

You almost certainly are missing a dependency on servlet-api

Comment: I righted click on my project, went to Build Path, configure Build Path, in Java build path and I have servlet-api.jar - usr/local/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.5/lib clicked but it still doesn't work ... any better way to do this?

Comment: Can't you just manually add "extends HttpServlet" to your class declaration?

Comment: it's not supposed to be like that in the tutorial package but I changed it too: package com.sdzee.servlets;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;

public class Test extends HttpServlet {
    
} Hopefully it will not block my tutorial, still I wonder why it doesn't show up ...

Comment: Just because eclipse failed momentarily doesn't mean the code is wrong.